# How to get the max-width in li element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ex(pseudo-code):

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="extended">
    <div class="columns column1">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="extended">
    <div class="columns column2">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
        <li>Item 8</li>
        <li>Item 9</li>
        <li>Item 10</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul class="menu">
  <li class="extended">
    <div class="columns column1">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="extended">
    <div class="columns column2">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 7</li>
        <li>Item 8</li>
        <li>Item 9</li>
        <li>Item 10</li>
        <li>Item 11</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the goal is to be like this:

```
Item 1 | Item 6
Item 2 | Item 7
Item 3 | Item 8
Item 4 | Item 9
Item 5 | Item 10
```

or

```
Item 1 | Item 7
Item 2 | Item 8
Item 3 | Item 9
Item 4 | Item 10
Item 5 | Item 11
Item 6
```

Question:
I want to get the max width of `column1` and `column2` then add the result and set as width of `main-wrapper`:
totalWidth = column1 + column2
$('.main-wrapper').css('width', totalWidth);

My implentation:

```
var $listing = $(this).find('ul.menu .extended ul li'); 
var $col1, $col2;
// Loop through all target submenu lists
$listing.each(function(key, value) {
   var $t = $(value);
   if(key == 0) {
   // Get the width of the first column
     $col1 = $t.outerWidth(true);
   } else if(key == $listing.length-1) {
     // Get the width of the second column
     $col2 = $t.outerWidth(true);
    }
});
// Store the total width of columns in variable
var $total_width = $col1 + $col2 + 46;  
// Append the width in the parent ul element
$(this).find('ul.menu').css('width', $total_width);
```

But my script only get the width correctly if the text has no spaces.

Comment: Is there a point to setting the width to the sum of the two columns? I mean, could the CSS be structured to allow this to happen?

Comment: I agree with Hank; although it could be done with JavaScript, this looks like first and foremost a CSS problem. Could you please post your CSS as well? (It could also depend on what browsers you want to support in this situation, so providing target browsers can help us as well.)

Comment: I'm targeting all browsers as possible. Here is my entire JS and CSS
http://pastebin.com/BHi25L05 and http://pastebin.com/Tr4H3gu1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution to my question. Thanks guys for all the inputs.

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.menu = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {


      /** SOF Block: Populate the menu items to each columns **/
      var $lists = $('#navigation li.expanded ul.menu'); 

      // Loop through all target lists.
      $lists.each(function(i, e) {

        var $list = $(e);
        // Count all the items
        var $count_list = $(this).find('li').size();
        // Get the ceiling for first column
        var $sliced_list = Math.ceil($count_list / 2);

        if($count_list > 5) {

          //These are temporary variables.
          var $new_list = $('<ul>');
          var $list_item, $sub_list, $sub_set;

          // Set the number of items per column when less than 9
          if($count_list < 9) {
            // The number of items per column.
            var per_column = 5;
          } 

          // Dynamic number of items per column when more that or equal to 9
          if($count_list >= 9) {
            var per_column = $sliced_list;
          }

          // Calculate the amount of columns needed.
          var n = Math.ceil($list.find('li').length / per_column);

          // Loop through all columns.
          for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

            // Creates the sub list for the current column.
            $sub_list = $('<ul class="columns column' + (i + 1) + '">');
            // Gets the first set of list items from the original list and adds them to the sub list created above.
            $sub_set = $list.find('li').slice(0, per_column).appendTo($sub_list);
            // Creates a new list item and adds the sub list to it.
            $list_item = $('<li class="extended extended' + (i + 1) + '">').append($sub_list);
            // Add the newly created list item to the new list.
            $new_list.append($list_item);
            // Create a div with the class 'columnX' and wrap the sub list with it.
            //$sub_list.wrap('<div class="columns column' + (i + 1) + '"></div>');

          }

          // Replace the original list with the new one.
          $list.html($new_list.html());

        }
      }); 
      /** EOF Block: Populate the menu items to each columns **/

      /** SOF Block: Apply all necessary changes to focused menu items **/
      // Set all settings required on hover
      $('#navigation ul li.expanded').hover(function() {
        $(this).children().next('ul').css('display', 'block');
        $(this).addClass('hover'); 
        // Get the width of parent li
        var w = $(this).width();
        // Apply the width to the "div class='fix'" element to avoid overlapping
        $(this).children().next('div').css('width', w + 'px');      
      }, function() {
        $(this).children().next('ul').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
      });
      /** EOF Block: Remove all changes applied to all focused menu items on mouseouot **/    

    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is incredibly strange code, and you should investigate better ways to do this. In the meantime, I put your code in JSFiddle and youre $total_width is coming back as NaN - you should set your initial $col1 and $col2 = 0 - that will at least ensure you are getting a number value to work with.

EDIT: Alexander is correct - $().find() does return a jQuery object. In my test I removed this and did $.find() and there was no .each() function.

```
var $listing = $(this).find('ul.menu .extended ul li'); 
console.log($listing);

var $col1 = 0, $col2 = 0;

// Loop through all target submenu lists
$listing.each(function(key, value) {
   var $t = $(value);

   if(key == 0) {
   // Get the width of the first column

     $col1 = $t.outerWidth(true);
   } else if(key == $listing.length-1) {
     // Get the width of the second column
 $col2 = $t.outerWidth(true);
}
});
// Store the total width of columns in variable
var $total_width = $col1 + $col2 + 46; 

// Append the width in the parent ul element
$(this).find('ul.menu').css('width', $total_width);
```

I think that will do the trick.

Comment: $().find method always returns a jQuery object, not DOM element

Comment: My code is working fine except for menu link that has spaces or comma

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you let CSS determine the width of each "column" and add those values together.

Because .column1 and .column2 are list elements (`display: list-item;`), they will always have the same width as they will expand to fit the largest child item.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/cWsxZ/1/

Set them to `display: inline-block;` and the rest should be easy.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/uYW8B/1/

```
/* css */
li.expanded { display: inline-block; }​

/* js */
var totalWidth = $('.column1').width() + $('.column2').width();
$('.main-wrapper').width(totalWidth);​
```